# two sum solution not working not sure what is going wrong, how can I fix my solution?

Tags: python

Im doing the classic two sum question: 
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Here is my code, i dont know why is not working :

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]: 
        for num in nums: 
            result = []
            x = target - num
            if x in nums: 
                result.append(nums.index(x)) 
                result.append(nums.index(num))
                if nums.index(x)!=nums.index(num):
                    return result
```

Comment: Could you example for which is doesn't work ?

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is well, but you could ismplify it

- make is static, as it don't need a `self`
- directly buil the array on return, no need to create it before
- use `enumerate` to get the indice of the first number, this allows you to start looking for the next one, from the next indice so no need to check that it's not the same, and use directly in the result
- return empty list of not found

```
@staticmethod
def twoSum(nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
    for idx, num in enumerate(nums):
        x = target - num
        if x in nums[idx + 1:]:
            return [idx, nums.index(x)]
    return []

print(Solution.twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 10))  # [0,8]
print(Solution.twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 15))  # [5,8]
print(Solution.twoSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2))   # []
```

Comment: Im confused what the "idx" part is in your code, could you explain? @azro

Comment: @puranikman look for enumerate doc, it gives the object like classic iteration and the index, 0,1,2,3,4...